# How can I convert xlm serialise image to binary formate

Tags: crystal-reports, fingerprint, crystal-reports-2008, binary-image

i am working with biometric device Digital Persona UrU 4500. I am saving finger print data in xlm serialise formate like this

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Fid>
    <Bytes>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</Bytes>
    <Format>1769473</Format>
    <Version>1.0.0</Version>
</Fid>
```

Above is xlmserialise fingerprint.

How can I convert this in image format? I am using `nvarchar(max)` field in the database. I want to convert this serialized data to binary image format so that I can show the user fingerprint on Crystal Reports.

Otherwise, is it possible to show a XML serialized image on Crystal Reports?

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to do this using a UFL.
Please make an rpt with saved data (including the xlm column) available so I can test.